# StreamReader,StreamWriter

Tags: c#, файлы

Как записать в файл информацию, чтобы информация, которая в файле была до этого, сохранилась. P.S. Этот код не работает:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO; // Нужно для открытия файлов,обязательно
namespace nomid
{
    class HardFiles
    {
        static public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Не  нагружает процессор

            string name = "ForFiles.txt";
            Console.WriteLine("Введите что-то");
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(name);
            sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd() + text); // Ничего не удалится
            sw.Close();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(name);
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
            sr.Close();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У **[StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx)** вторым параметром можно передать флаг, который позволяет сказать, что будут добавлены строки. **true** для добавления данных в файл. **false** - Перезаписать файл.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(name, true);
                                           ^---
```

еще можно сделать финт

```
StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(name);
```

Comment: Спасибо,всё работает!

Comment: Что такое финт?

Comment: @TarasYaitskiy финт - это не из программирования термин ;-)